# Turn Off Sound and screen blink on incoming calls in Android?

Tags: android, audio

I would like to know whether this is actually possible in Android?

When Android phone receives an incoming call from a specific number the phone's ringing should stop and also the screen should not blink. What I mean is the user should not be able to know that there was incoming call, but actually there was.

I do not want to delete any call logs, just to stop sound on incoming call from a specific number and that too at a specific time.

Can someone let me know if this is actually possible?

Comment: You can always set the ring tone to something silent for that particular number. as for the non flashing, no idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When Android phone receives an
>   incoming call from a specific number
>   the phone's ringing should stop and
>   also the screen should not blink. What
>   I mean is the user should not be able
>   to know that there was incoming call,
>   but actually there was.

Fortunately, this should not be possible from the SDK. You can be notified that a phone call comes in, but I do not believe you can stop the ringtone, and I am really sure you cannot stop the in-call screen from appearing.

Comment: oh, even I thought so. Anyways thanks a lot for assuring me that it is indeed not possible.